# SQL query long time excution time

Tags: mysql, drupal

I have a drupal website which has a particular SQL query which is taking roughly around 15-16 seconds to execute is there any way to reduce this execution time ?

Below is the query

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data.nid AS field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data_nid
FROM 
node node
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_events_categories field_data_field_events_categories ON node.nid = field_data_field_events_categories.entity_id AND (field_data_field_events_categories.entity_type = :views_join_condition_? AND field_data_field_events_categories.deleted = :views_join_condition_?)
LEFT JOIN taxonomy_term_data taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories ON field_data_field_events_categories.field_events_categories_tid = taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories.tid
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_events_categories taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories__field_data_field_events_categories ON taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories.tid = taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories__field_data_field_events_categories.field_events_categories_tid AND (taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories__field_data_field_events_categories.entity_type = :views_join_condition_? AND taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories__field_data_field_events_categories.deleted = :views_join_condition_?)
LEFT JOIN node field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data ON taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories__field_data_field_events_categories.entity_id = field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data.nid
INNER JOIN taxonomy_index field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data__taxonomy_index ON field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data.nid = field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data__taxonomy_index.nid
WHERE (( (field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data.nid != :node_nid OR field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data.nid IS NULL) AND (field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data__taxonomy_index.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_?) )AND(( (node.status = :db_condition_placeholder_?) AND (node.type IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_?)) )))
ORDER BY field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data_nid DESC
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

Comment: It looks like the query is auto generated by the views module, if you want some help it might be better to explain what you are trying to do and giving details of your content structure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each table you're using in this query must have indexes. Check them and create if necessary.
2. Try to avoid JOINs because they are really slow.

Comment: These are tables auto generated by Drupal, they allready have indexes, also join are usually less slow than nested query.

Answer (score 0):

It might be like this if I did not missed something

```
SELECT 
node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data.nid AS field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data_nid
FROM 
(select * from node 
        where  
            (node.status = :db_condition_placeholder_?) 
            AND 
            (node.type IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_?))) node 
LEFT JOIN 
    field_data_field_events_categories 
        ON 
            node.nid = field_data_field_events_categories.entity_id 
        AND 
            (field_data_field_events_categories.entity_type = :views_join_condition_? 
            AND 
            field_data_field_events_categories.deleted = :views_join_condition_?)
LEFT JOIN 
    taxonomy_term_data taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories 
        ON 
            field_data_field_events_categories.field_events_categories_tid = taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories.tid
LEFT JOIN 
    field_data_field_events_categories taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories__field_data_field_events_categories 
        ON 
            taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories.tid = taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories__field_data_field_events_categories.field_events_categories_tid 
        AND 
            (taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories__field_data_field_events_categories.entity_type = :views_join_condition_? 
            AND 
            taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories__field_data_field_events_categories.deleted = :views_join_condition_?)
LEFT JOIN 
    node field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data 
        ON 
            taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_events_categories__field_data_field_events_categories.entity_id = field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data.nid
INNER JOIN 
    taxonomy_index field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data__taxonomy_index 
        ON 
            field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data.nid = field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data__taxonomy_index.nid
WHERE 
    (    
        (field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data.nid != :node_nid OR field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data.nid IS NULL) 
        AND 
        (field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data__taxonomy_index.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_?)      
    )
ORDER BY field_events_categories_taxonomy_term_data_nid DESC
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```